# select rows from MySQL where col1 is value and another row where col1 is not value based on col2 related values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my MySQL database which has columns:

- callid
- event

I want to select all rows where the event is 'ENTERQUEUE' which i am doing in the below query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log
WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
  AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-07'
  AND event = 'ENTERQUEUE'
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

But i only want to show the number of rows where the event column is not equal to `CONNECT` where `callid` is equal to the `callid` column from the above query

UPDATE:

What happens is, when a call comes into the database a row is inserted

example:

```
callid - 1234
event - ENTERQUEUE
```

then as the call circles round without being answered this data is inserted:

```
callid - 1234
event - RINGNOANSWER
```

then once the call is answered, the data

```
callid - 1234
event - CONNECT
```

and once the call is hung up

```
callid - 1234
event - COMPLETEAGENT or COMPLETEAGENT
```

if the caller hangs up before being answered

```
callid - 1234
event - ABANDON
```

so when the caller is waiting there are only ever rows with events ENTERQUEUE or RINGNOANSWER

i want to show the number of rows for the above, what query do i need for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are faster ways of performing this query, but here is one.

Baiscally what you want is to get all RINGNOANSWERs which are NOT followed by a CONNECT or ABANDON. So you could first get all CONNECT/ABANDONS and then look for all RINGNOANSWERs with a callid not equal to the connect/abadon-list... exactly what you want. You could do it like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `callid`) FROM `voipnow`.`ast_queue_log` WHERE `event`='RINGNOANSWER' AND `callid` NOT IN (SELECT `callid` FROM `voipnow`.`ast_queue_log` WHERE `event`='CONNECT' OR `event`='ABANDON')
```

Comment: this seems to show a count of 25 but i know there are not that many rows?

Comment: if i do SELECT * it shows the row with event of ENTERQUEUE and rows with event of RINGNOANSWER but there is no connect event so it shouldn't display

Comment: oh sorry, it should either be a COUNT(DISTINCT `callid`) or an added WHERE `event`='ENTERQUEUE' at the end. Either is fine. (edited the post)

Comment: i tried using COUNT(DISTINCT callid) but it still shows a count of '1'

Comment: ugh, I'm tired; typed "where event" instead of "and event" :|

Comment: i realised too it needed changing to AND rather than WHERE - this still shows one row with the event of ENTERQUEUE

Comment: Hmm... let's see... in the second case, since you already have a 1:1 relation between rows and callid's (I assume each callid can have only 1 BEGINQUEUE event), changing it to count retrieved rows (`COUNT(*)`) should work.

Comment: i run this query SELECT * 
FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
WHERE time > '2014-03-10 22:00:00'
AND callid NOT IN 
(SELECT callid FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
WHERE event = 'CONNECT') AND event = 'ENTERQUEUE' and it shows just the one row with an event of ENTERQUEUE

Comment: No, it shows that only 1 event exists with an ENTERQUEUE, but without a CONNECT.

Comment: aha i see - is there a way to make it not show that row. i only want to show waiting callers (rows with event of ENTERQUEUE and RINGNOANSWER but no CONNECT)

Comment: i guess i could run an if statement in PHP to not display any results if the event equals ENTERQUEUE? unless there is any easy way in the SQL Query ?

Comment: then select all RINGNOANSWER which do not have CONNECT. Basically adapt the above query to `select .... where... NOT IN (select ... where event='CONNECT') AND event='RINGNOANSWER'`

Comment: changing ENTERQUEUE to RINGNOANSWER shows 3 rows because they still exist with no CONNECT

Comment: as an example, i have rows with a callid of 1394488858.974449 4 rows (3 RINGNOANSWER , meaning the call has gone round in a circle 3 times and 1 ABANDON because the caller hung up before answered. if the call was answered it would be 3 RINGNOANSWER , meaning the call has gone round in a circle 3 times and 1 CONNECT because the caller was answered

Comment: Then I'm confused how exactly the relations between all these is. Personally I would switch the single event-table to a two (or event three-) table layout so you could easily just left-join one on the other, and based on that select whichever you want. But I must admit I'm a bit confused how your system works now... Sorry. Perhaps someone else can help ?

Comment: a call comes in - row inserted with callid 1234 and event ENTERQUEUE

Comment: it goes round in a circle, say twice, it will insert 2 rows with the same callid and event of RINGNOANSWER

Comment: then the call is answered, callid inserted again (1234) and event CONNECT. if the caller hangs up before being answered rather than CONNECT it will be ABANDON

Comment: so if the caller is waiting (which is the number/count i want to show) there will be rows with ENTERQUEUE and RINGNOANSWER with no rows where event is CONNECT or ABANDON

Comment: does that now make sense okay?

Comment: Try it like this then. Updated the answer to your last explenation

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to build a result-set of all records that have a valid 'CONNECT' event.  You can then use a join to prune, leaving only those records that aren't in the sub-query's results:

```
SELECT count(1)
  FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log A
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT callid 
               FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log
              WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
                AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-07'
                AND event = 'CONNECT') B
    ON A.callid = B.callid
 WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
   AND DATE(A.time) = '2014-03-07'
   AND A.event = 'ENTERQUEUE'
   AND B.callid IS NULL;
```

Comment: this is returning one row with an event of ENTERQUEUE, check the comments on the above answer

Comment: a call comes in - row inserted with callid 1234 and event ENTERQUEUE
---
it goes round in a circle, say twice, it will insert 2 rows with the same callid and event of RINGNOANSWER
---
then the call is answered, callid inserted again (1234) and event CONNECT. if the caller hangs up before being answered rather than CONNECT it will be ABANDON
--- 
so if the caller is waiting (which is the number/count i want to show) there will be rows with ENTERQUEUE and RINGNOANSWER with no rows where event is CONNECT or ABANDON